# Why use ImageView when we have WebView?

Tags: android, webview, imageview

This might seem to you guys as a stupid question, but it comes into my mind so many times:

Why is there an `ImageView` in Android? We have a `WebView`, which is capable of displaying images, and so much more stuff. So why would you provide an `ImageView` as well? Maybe there is some fundamental reason for this, but I just don't see it. Whenever I want to use some media, I try to use a `WebView`, because this allows me to change the type of media if I wish to do so, and I do not need another Type of `View`.

*So to not make this question to broad, let's bring it down to this:*

In which scenario does an `ImageView` have big advantages over a `WebView`?

**EDIT**

*And a second question:*

If I have some audio, some html-text and some pictures, which are stored locally on my device, would I use one `WebView` to display them, or would I use one Type of View for each Type of media?

Comment: for me it is all about interaction beside size and performance issues. web view housing complex layouts and scrolling where image view is doing a single display.

Comment: Why have a GLASS when we have a JUG. Simply because they have specific applications and uses.

Comment: You can build HTML5 applications using just the webviews if you wish, its not natively handled by the operating system though, so you will get some minor slow down. There is also more flexibility with the ImageView in subclassing, adding extra functionality etc, which is natively built into Java as a programming language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebView is a much more expensive widget to use, in terms of memory consumption, than is ImageView.

The reason for the memory cost of WebView is the fact that WebView is powered by a fairly complete copy of WebKit. WebKit is an open source Web rendering engine that forms the heart of major Web browsers, such as Chrome and Safari. While the version of WebKit that lives in Android is one optimized for mobile use, it still represents a fairly substantial code base, and rendering complex Web pages takes up a fair amount of RAM (as anyone with lots of browser tabs on their desktop knows all too well).

Answer (score 1):

**FACT:** The `WebView` implementation is such that it will consume more memory if used to download & display images. **Always**. Also, `ImageView` has special methods / XML tags for cropping, resizing, scaling & manipulating images (which `WebView` doesn`t).

Comment: Ok this is an argument. But would this affect my application in any serious way if I only use 2 or 3 webviews in one activity?

Comment: On low-end devices with less RAM or older OS versions, loading a `WebView` is noticeably laggy.

Answer (score 0):

A person has a image in the gallery. The persom wants to show it inside the app. What will it do?

Go and host it on an online image hosting website and then pass the url to the WebView?

That ain't a cool Idea.. and people and Google understand that.

Comment: the picture must not be online to load it to a WebView

Comment: A webview takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically image view using for showing image from gallery , drawable or url.Webview for handling or showing web content or html kind of thing.

Comment: yes this is what came into my mind as well. But is there any argument that speaks against using WebView to display locally stored images?

Answer (score 0):

Well ImageView consumes less memory. ImageView can change the image display options. 
ImageView can display images from different sources like "Resources, drawables".
WebView mainly for displaying html pages.